# How to make C# app for taskbar to display messages

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

I have a restaurant WINFORM app , and its connected to website for online orders. I want to notify user if there is any new online order. 
However I tried using on same C# app with timer , but its slowing and sometime freezes the whole app. 
So now I have decided to make another app just to check if theirs any new order, however I want it to stick to taskbar as a message board which blinks and if possible displays

> "Online pending order : 02" .

I am able to make it Blink in taskbar by changing the icons by using timer, if new online order.
So let me know if its possible.

This is an example I drew in mspaint to illustrate what I am trying to do.And this red box blinks or text blinks either way
[image: This is how I want it to be]

Thanks

Comment: maybe, NotifyIcon (WinForms) will suit your needs?

Comment: Keep in mind the way to show Notifications has changed with Windows 8, 2 and a half years ago. It's one of the things in Windows 8 that's still around in Windows 10.